# Почему после «снег» ставится запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Шëл снег, густой и белый, от снега в комнате светло.

Answer (score 3):

Определения, стоящие после определяемого слова, могут обособляться или не обособляться в зависимости от ряда факторов. Эта тема раскрывается в справочнике Розенталя ([**Обособленные определения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108)).

Приведенное предложение является искаженной частью стихотворения Александра Твардовского «Утро» ([**КУЛЬТУРА.РФ**](https://www.culture.ru/poems/6966/utro)):

*Кружась легко и неумело,

Снежинка села на стекло.

**Шёл ночью снег густой и белый —

От снега в комнате светло.**

Чуть порошит пушок летучий,

И солнце зимнее встаёт.

Как каждый день — полней и лучше,

Полней и лучше Новый год…*

Как видим, запятой нет. Тире разделяет простые предложения с бессоюзной причинно-следственной связью.

> В стихотворной речи на обособление или необособления определений оказывают влияние интонация произношения, ритм стиха. *В поле чистом серебрится снег **волнистый** и **рябой*** (П.); *Сидит на камне между ними лезгинец **дряхлый** и **седой*** (Л.).

Answer (score 1):

Запятые при определительных оборотах.

Запятыми выделяются причастия и прилагательные, поставленные после определяемого существительного с целью придать им более самостоятельное значение и не имеющие при себе пояснительных слов, особенно в тех случаях, когда перед существительным уже есть определяющее слово.

Пушкин:

> *Mаша, бледная и трепещущая, подошла к Ивану Кузьмичу.*

> *Сосед мой, молодой казак, стройный и красивый, налил мне стакан простого вина.*

Толстой:

> *Завтра увижу Сережу и Алексея Александровича, и пойдет моя жизнь, хорошая и привычная, по-старому.*

> *Талия ее, очень тонкая, казалась еще тоньше.*

Более подробно обо всех остальных случаях можно почитать на сайте Грамоты: http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/150-zap-19-31